# Django queryset with Q object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to perform a filter operation on my queryset of the form 
(x=True) or ((x=False) and (some other condition)). When i try the following command, i get an error. Any suggestions.

Operation

```
Item.objects.filter(mission_id__in=mission_ids).exclude(id__in=attempted_items).filter(
            answers_left_count__gte=1, is_active=True, is_test_data=False
    ).values_list("mission_id", 'mission__items_per_mission', 'mission__send_remaining_items').annotate(
            Count('id')  # Get item count
    ).filter(Q(mission__send_remaining_items=True) | (
    Q(mission__send_remaining_items=False), Q(id__count__gte=F('mission__items_per_mission') + 1))).values_list(
            "mission_id", flat=True)
```

Error

```
TypeError: (<Q: (AND: ('mission__send_remaining_items__is', False))>, <Q: (AND: ('id__count__gte', <CombinedExpression: F(mission__items_per_mission) + Value(1)>))>)
```

Comment: What is the tuple of Q`s supposed to achieve?

Comment: @dhke I have updated my question

Comment: if you share your model and the output you want to see, it will be helpful to get accurate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to perform a filter operation on my queryset of the form (x=True) or ((x=False) and (some other condition))

`AND` is only `,` for `Q` objects when directly passed to `filter()`, i.e.

```
.filter(Q(), Q())
```

But that's because of how `filter()` processes its arguments, not the result of combining two `Q` objects.

ANDing `Q` objects is done via [`&`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
.filter(Q() & Q())
```

So your query becomes

```
.filter(Q() | (Q() & Q()))
```